# Using a xml file as an option file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a Windows Service that uses a xml as on option file to monitor a directory, when a new file is detected in it, this file is renamed, sent by mail to a specified list of users and moved to an archive directory.

The option file used to be like this and the user would replace to what he needs everytime :

```
<Options>
    <ExportDir>path/to/export/directory</ExportDir>
    <ArchiveDir>path/to/archive/directory</ArchiveDir>
    <MailTo>
        <Mail>fake1@mail.com</Mail>
        <Mail>fake2@mail.com</Mail>
        <Mail>fake3@mail.com</Mail>
    </MailTo>
</Options>
```

Parsing with :

```
List<string> mail = new List<string>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"path/to/xml/file");

XmlNode NodeExportDir = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ExportDir");
string ExportDir= NodeExportDir.InnerText;

XmlNode NodeArchiveDir = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ArchiveDir");
string ArchiveDir = NodeArchiveDir.InnerText;

XmlNodeList listAddress = doc.SelectNodes("//MailTo");
foreach (XmlNode node in listAddress)
{
    foreach (XmlNode mailAddress in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        mail.Add(mailAddress.InnerText);
    }
}
```

I want to improve it so it is possible to have several options without deleting everytime. So the xml file now looks like :

```
<Options>
    <ExportDir path = "path/to/export/directory">
        <ArchiveDir>path/to/archive/directory</ArchiveDir>
        <MailTo>
            <Mail>fake1@mail.com</Mail>
            <Mail>fake2@mail.com</Mail>
            <Mail>fake3@mail.com</Mail>
        </MailTo>
    </ExportDir>
    <ExportDir path = "path/to/export/directory2">
        <ArchiveDir>path/to/archive/directory2</ArchiveDir>
        <MailTo>
            <Mail>fake4@mail.com</Mail>
            <Mail>fake5@mail.com</Mail>
            <Mail>fake6@mail.com</Mail>
        </MailTo>
    </ExportDir>
</Options>
```

When there is only one ExportDir, I still manage to parse and put results in needed variables with this code :

```
List<string> mail = new List<string>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"path/to/xml/file");

XmlNodeList NodeExportDir = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ExportDir");
for (int i = 0; i < NodeExportDir.Count; i++)
{
    string ExportDir = NodeExportDir[i].Attributes["path"].Value;
}

XmlNodeList NodeArchiveDir = doc.SelectNodes("//ArchiveDir");
foreach (XmlNode node in NodeArchiveDir)
{
    foreach (XmlNode dirArch in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        string ArchiveDir = dirArch.InnerText;
    }
}

XmlNodeList listAddress = doc.SelectNodes("//MailTo");
foreach (XmlNode node in listAddress)
{
    foreach (XmlNode mailAddress in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        mail.Add(mailAddress.InnerText);
    }
}
```

But when there are more than one, of course it doesn't work as I'd like.

How can I use the archive directory and the mail addresses according to where the user drops a file (which is the ExportDir).

**Update :**

Thanks to [ivcubr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444573/9365158) I can now select the informations corresponding to an ExportDir path like so :

```
foreach (DossierExport test in options)
{
    if (test.Path == "path/to/export/directory")
    {
        string ArchiveDir = test.Archive;
        foreach (string mailAddr in test.Mail)
        {
            mail.Add(mailAddr);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I make a general solution so I don't have to add code everytime a new ExportDir path is created in the xml file ?

Comment: Is there anything tying you to `XmlDocument` rather than using LINQ to XML and `XDocument`? LINQ to XML is a *much* nicer API to use.

Comment: Why not create classes to represent the options and use XDocument or XmlSerializer to read/store the entire object graph at once?

Comment: @AndyJ Yep, fixed

Comment: @DaisyShipton Not really, that's how I learned to parse xml files so that's how I do it when I start working on stuff. Would LINQ to XML help in this case ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting, how could I store and read only the archive directory and mail addresses corresponding to the export directory path ?

Comment: LINQ to XML would make it easier to query the document, yes. Not *massively* simpler, but just a bit nicer. I think it's well worth you learning more.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'll try switching to it then, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are most comfortable with `XmlDocument` the following should work for you. Here I would recommend creating a class to hold each option and then later you can just loop through all of these and use the properties parsed from the XML file.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"test.xml");

List<ExportDirectory> options = new List<ExportDirectory>();
XmlNodeList nodeExportDir = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ExportDir");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeExportDir) {
    ExportDirectory exportDirectory = new ExportDirectory() {
        Path = node.Attributes["path"].Value,
        Archive = node.SelectSingleNode("ArchiveDir").InnerText
    };

    foreach (XmlNode mail in node.SelectNodes("MailTo/Mail")) {
        exportDirectory.Mail.Add(mail.InnerText);
    }
    options.Add(exportDirectory);
}
```

Export Directory class:

```
public class ExportDirectory {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Archive { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mail { get; set; }

    public ExportDirectory() {
        Mail = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding your added question, why do you need to have `if (test.Path == "path/to/export/directory")`? Why not eliminate the `if` statement and go with:

```
foreach (DossierExport test in options)
{
    string ArchiveDir = test.Archive;
    foreach (string mailAddr in test.Mail)
    {
        mail.Add(mailAddr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. This piece of code throws a `System.NullReferenceException` on the `exportDirectory.Mail.Add(mail.InnerText);` line that I don't find how to fix

Comment: Nevermind, I just forgot to initialize the Mail list. So, now that my options list is filled, how do I manipulate it when importing a file to an ExportDir ?

Comment: @A.Petit I added my class definition (i forgot to add it before) which initializes the list in the constructor. Not sure what you mean by 'manipulate it'?

Comment: @A.Petit see my edited answer if that answers your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!